# Let $S \subset C$.If $S$ is finite set,show that the set of functions $z \in S \mapsto z^j$ for $j \in Z_+ <\#S$ is linearly indepedent

Tags: linear-algebra, independence

Let $S \subset C$.If $S$ is finite set,show that the set of functions $z \in S \mapsto z^j$ for $j \in Z_+ <\#S$ is linearly indepedent and if $\#S$ is not finite ,show that the set of the same functions with $j \in Z_+$ is linearly indepedent

This was a subquestion of proving the determinant of Vandermonde.How i can show this two proves?

Comment: Hint: How many zeros can a polynomial of a given degree have?

Comment: how i can use this for my problem i don't get it

Comment: Let's call the function $S \to \Bbb{C}, z \mapsto z^j$ simply $f_j$ and let $N := \#S$. Linear independence means that if $p := \sum_{n=1}^N \alpha_j f_j \equiv 0$, then $\alpha_j = 0$ for all $j$.  To show this, note that $p$ is a polynomial and that we are assuming $p \equiv 0$ on $S$. Now, how many zeros can $p$ have (at most) if not all coefficients of $p$ vanish?

Comment: It is N so $a_j =0$ , for not finite S is the same ?

Comment: Yes, for infinite $\#S$, it is the same, since a (nonzero) polynomial can only have finitely many zeros.